# Issue with highchart data display when parsing JSON data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I am trying to dynamically fetch the data from a PhP module, load it as JSON data into javascript and use this data to generate a Pie chart using HighCharts. The Pie chart is generating properly when I am using some static data but not loading when I am parsing JSON data and feeding that as input to the Highchart series object. I am sure this is something to do with the formatting of data while inputting to Highcharts but I am not able to figure that out for sometime now :( So thought would just reach out to you guys . I have attached the code here and the sample json output generated by the php module for your reference.

Sample JSON input generated from PhP module : [{"skill":"html","count":"158"},{"skill":"css","count":"134"}]. Need to parse this JSON input and feed as input to my HighCharts series object to generate a pie-chart showing "html" and "css" as pie-slices.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Top Skills Analytics</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="highcharts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><u><b><font size="4">Top Skills Analysis</font></b></u>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="container" style="height: 500px; width: 500px; margin-bottom: 1em;"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Creates the HighChart using the dynamically generated data from PhP module
        function loadCharts() {
            // Parses the JSON data and returns an array of an array
            var result = [];
            // json from php is like : [{"skill":"html","count":"158"},{"skill":"css","count":"134"}]
            $.getJSON('test.php', function (json) {
                $.each(json, function (i, entry) {
                    result.push(entry.skill, entry.count);
                });
            });
            //result = [["html",158],["css",134]];  --> this works

            var options1 = {
                "series": [{
                    "name": "Jobs",
                    "type": "pie",
                    "sliced": true,
                    "data": result, // works when populated with static value like [["html",158],["css",134]]
                    "pointWidth": 15,
                    "color": "#C6D9E7",
                    "borderColor": "#8BB6D9",
                    "shadow": true,
                }],
                "title": {
                    "text": "Top Skills Analytics"
                },
                "legend": {
                    "layout": "vertical",
                    "style": {
                        "left": "auto",
                        "bottom": "auto",
                        "right": "auto",
                        "top": "auto"
                    }
                },
                "chart": {
                    "renderTo": "container"
                },
                "credits": {
                    "enabled": false
                }

            };

            var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options1);
        }

        // Load the charts when the webpage loads for the first time
        $(document).ready(function () {
            loadCharts();
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/K9Ajq/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works with static data because the count is an int

```
["html",158]
```

And it doesn't work with dynamic data because it returns a string count

```
{"skill":"html","count":"158"}
```

Notice the double quotes around the second code line?
You need to either cast your string to an int in php or in javascript before passing it to highcharts

And another thing, if you run the code highcharts should complain with an error

```
Uncaught Highcharts error #14: www.highcharts.com/errors/14
```

If you visit the link it basically says the same thing about strings.

There is another thing wrong with the code

```
[["html",158],["css",134]]
```

As you can see here we have an array of arrays and when we run your code with string to int parsing we get

```
["html", 158, "css", 134]
```

Notice the problem? We have an array of four elements.
What you need to do is:

```
result.push([entry.skill, entry.count]);
```

Push an array of two elements to the result variable and don't forget that count must be an int

Comment: Thanks @metame. I see the mistakes that I was doing and I have fixed it now to generate the proper pie chart. I really need to improve my JS skills :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
result.push([entry.skill, parseInt(entry.count)]);
```

Comment: this will result having '["html", 158, "css", 134]' how can that help ?

Comment: Thanks Jugal. I incorporated your suggestion to build on the solution given by @metame and it worked !!

Comment: ohhh @MinaGabriel my bad, terrible mistake !!!! corrected, i forgot the `[]` Thanks